# Turn Byte Array in Decimal Representation Data Into an Excecutable

Tags: swift

So, in my server I have data I got from an API whose contents look like this, it is an mp3 file.

```
210, 107, 180, 171, 213, 120, 193, 203, 10, 254, 198, 165, 46, 178, 201, 97, 205, 122, 30, 135, 212, 173, 59, 201, 66, 153, 112, 64, 104, 92, 85, 105, 8, 128, 213, 233, 136, 130, 57, 226, 129, 162, 48, 224, 17, 193, 128, 20, 171, 17, 158, 7, 15, 12, 24, 128, 113, 129, 135, 3, 3, 76, 36, 32, 198, 192, 204, 44, 104, 18, 20, 97, 1, 36, 129, 196, 64, 132, 160
```

and so on...

In the server I can take that data and write it into the file system as an mp3... but when I send that data to my client (**Swift iOS**) I get an mp3 file that does not play and when opened in a text editor the same numbers appear, instead of making it an executable audio mp3 file.

Here is how I implemented that:

```
func getAudioRawData() async throws {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.104:8080/audio") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
    
    guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { fatalError("Error while fetching data") }
    print("Async audio", data)
    //IMPORTANT LINE ----->>>>>> print(writeToFile(data: data, fileName: "output")); <<<<<
    
}


func writeToFile(data: Data, fileName: String) -> URL? {
    // get path of directory
    guard let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        return nil
    }
    // create file url
    let fileurl =  directory.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).mp3")
// if file exists then write data
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileurl.path) {
        if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileurl.path) {
            // seekToEndOfFile, writes data at the last of file(appends not override)
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.write(data)
            fileHandle.closeFile()
        }
        else {
            print("Can't open file to write.")
        }
    }
    else {
        // if file does not exist write data for the first time
        do{
            try data.write(to: fileurl, options: .atomic)
        }catch {
            print("Unable to write in new file.")
        }
    }
    return directory
}
```

SO the directory does return and the file is written, therefore my code has no errors as it does what I tell it to, but I don't know hoe to tell it to make that data into something an mp3 file can read and execute.